# How to fix syntax error in postgresql UPSERT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, upsert

I'm trying to learn postgresql's upsert syntax but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "name"
LINE 5:     SET name = EXCLUDED.name;
```

this is the sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, fav_num) 
VALUES ('bob', 2) 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET fav_num = EXCLUDED.fav_num, 
SET name = EXCLUDED.name;
```

I tried changing the excluded.fav_num and excluded.name to values but I still encounter the same error. I'm running PostgreSQL 10.6. What should be the proper query?

Table:

```
|------|------|---------|
|  id  | name | fav_num |
|------|------|---------|
|  1   | bob  |    1    |
|------|------|---------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `SET` as in:

```
SET fav_num = EXCLUDED.fav_num, name = EXCLUDED.name
```

Note *one* and only one `SET`.

Comment: From the link below: The action can be:

 `DO NOTHING` – means do nothing if the row already exists in the table.
 `DO UPDATE SET column_1 = value_1, .. WHERE condition` – update some fields in the table.

Comment: It's the same as `UPDATE`.

Comment: Ohh my bad cause most of the example in the internet only has one column so I figured the "..." was another set. It works thank you